# How can I graph a numerical function using Python and Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph the Sigmoid Function used in machine learning by using the Matplotlib library. My problem is that I haven't visualized a mathematical function before so I'm humbly asking for your guidance.

I've tried to directly plot the following function:

```
def Sigmoid(x):
  a=[]
  for i in x:
    a.append(1/(1+math.exp(-i)))
  return a
```

using the command `plt.plot(Sigmoid)`.
But that gave me the error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

The final result should look something like this:

[image: 1]

Comment: Try this `plot.plot(Sigmoid(10))`

Comment: @Hackaholic I think you mean `range(10)`, not `10`.

Comment: Follow the 1st tutorial https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html

Comment: @PMende yea right

Comment: Guys, non of these solutions worked for me. So, I added two lines of code based on the answers I received:                                                                                     `x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = Sigmoid(x)`.                                                                                       Apparently, I had to define an interval range for the x-axis and let y be the function itself. This means that for every value the function ouputs, Matplotlib will graph it on the interval -5<x<5...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sigmoid` is a function, Matplotlib expects numerical values, i.e., the results of a function evaluation, e.g.

```
x = [i/50 - 1 for i in range(101)]
plt.plot(x, Sigmoid(x))
```

That said, you probably want to familiarize with the [Numpy](https://www.numpy.org/) library

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
plt.plot(x, 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(arr, scale=1):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    result = 1/(1 + np.exp(-arr*scale))
    return result

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = sigmoid(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

Result:

[image]

The `ax.plot` method takes a pair of 1-D array-likes that are of the same length to create the lines. Matplotlib is not like Mathematica in which you can give an analytic function and a domain of its arguments. You have to give (in this case) x-y pairs (or rather, lists/arrays that can be *turned* into x-y pairs) And in this case, order matters.

Comment: x is already an array. Why are you again converting it to an array  inside the function ?

Comment: @Sheldore The input doesn't necessarily *have* to be an array. `np.asarray` will use the array *as-is* (i.e., won't copy it) if it's already a numpy array. Otherwise, it converts it.

Comment: My comment was in the context of your posted answer, not a generality.